# accessor-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C.

I need to know how to access the instance variable using the accessors. 
I could able to access integer variables but not the character variable which i have declared here. 
Please correct if there is any wrong in this code below.

```
#define SIZE = 4096

 @interface data : NSObject

  {

    unsigned char id[SIZE];
  }


  @property(readwrite)unsigned char id[SIZE];

  @end

  @implementation data

  @synthesize unsigned char id[SIZE];

  @end

  main.m

  someClass* classPointer = [[someClass alloc]init];

  data* dt = [[data alloc]init];

  [classPointer createMessage:data.id];
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the implementation and interface in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an instance of `NSString` or `NSData` for the instance variable instead of an array of chars? For example:

```
@interface Foo2 : NSObject
{
    NSString *_dataId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dataId;

@end


@implementation Foo2

@synthesize dataId = _dataId;

@end
```

Otherwise you'd have to do something along these lines:

```
#define DATA_ID_SIZE 4096

@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    char _dataID[DATA_ID_SIZE];
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) const char *dataID;

@end

@implementation Foo

// Returns a copy of the internal array of chars.
- (const char *)dataID
{
    size_t length = strlen(_dataID);
    // Dynamically allocate an array of chars to return.
    char *buf = malloc(length);
    // Copy the values from the internal array.
    memcpy(buf, _dataID, length);

    return buf;
}

- (void)setDataID:(const char *)dataID
{
    // Copy provided chars into the internal array.
    memcpy(_dataID, dataID, DATA_ID_SIZE);
    // To be on the safe side, copy null character to the last element.
    _dataID[DATA_ID_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
}
```

By the way, `id` is a data type in Objective-C, so it's best not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: thanks for explaining me in detail.Its very useful for a beginner like me.I tried the program.I just unsigned before every char declaraion and definitions and i have one warning which i could not able to clear.Its "Pointer targets is passing argument 1 of 'strlen' differ in signedness" in size_t length = strlen(_dataID);.

Comment: You can cast `_dataID` to `(const char *)` to get rid of the warning, like so:  `size_t length = strlen((const char *)_dataID);`

Comment: Its working fine with (const char *).I changed (const char*)(unsigned const char*).I did size_t length = strlen((unsigned const char*)_dataID);I am getting the same "Pointer target argument 1 of strlen" error.

Comment: Yeah it got fixed.Thanks jlehr.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set `id` anywhere, so it's just going to be nil.

Also on a side note, you must release the objects that you alloc init.

Comment: Your synthesize statement does not look correct. Should be: @synthesize id;

Comment: It's impossible for a native C array to be null. It's also impossible to assign a variable defined as an array type.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to manage the memory is the sample above? `char c[size]` is an array and it will take sizeof(char) * size bytes as the class member, but the property declared in the same manner will read/write **pointer**, not the data! I suggest you to use **NSData*** (or NSMutableData) instead of C-array, it's the preferred way for Obj-C.

Comment: You can't modify a variable defined as an array type in C.